# Why is my value nil when i try to read from shared group using UserDefaults (watchOS)

Tags: ios, swift3, nsuserdefaults, watchkit, userdefaults

Hi i use a shared group to store a value in that i need to read from my watch but because of some reson, the value is **nil**.

i made a app group in the developer portal and i enabled and checked the app group in the application and watchkit extension under capabilities.

what else am i forgetting?
can someone help me please?

**IOS APP:**
MainViewController.swift

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(newUsername, forKey: "username")
    defaults.set(newCode, forKey: "password")
    defaults.synchronize()

    // when i print  defaults.string(forKey: "username")   here it
       returns me the username
```

**Watch Extension** InterfaceController.swift

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let userName = defaults.string(forKey: "username")!
    let password = defaults.string(forKey: "password")!

    // when i print  defaults.string(forKey: "username")   here it  
       returns me nil
```

I also tried to specify the defaults without luck.

```
let appGroupID = "group.tld.domain.appname"
if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupID) {
   defaults.setValue(username, forKey: "username")
   defaults.setValue(password, forKey: "password")
}
```

Comment: Sharing data by App Group is not longer valid since Watch OS 2. You should `Watch​Connectivity` instead. This guy had same question as yours. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3927

Answer (score 0):

If you needed to share data from iOS app to watch extension then you should use Session. Actually Userdefaults or core data's store data can not pass without session.

Comment: Hi, i am unfamiliar with sessions,  can you help me explaining more about it or how to adjust my code to get it to work?.
P.s. i cannot find much meaningfull of sessions in google

Comment: Hello Remco, did you get your solution or not.